# set, get and popitem performance of OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Since `OrderedDict` needs to maintain the insertion order of an item, I'm wondering what is the performance of `get`/`set`/`popitem` in Python 2.7? Haven't found any official documents so far. 
I'm guessing `get` is `O(1)`, `set` is `O(logN)` and `popitem` is `O(1)`.

Here's the `collection.OrdereDict` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: @Kun, thanks and vote up. I referred some documents and discussions online before asking. In the discussion you mentioned, it seems conclusion is set/get/popitem are all `O(1)`. But I do not find any official document mentioning they are truly `O(1)`. BTW, if you read my post, my question is where is the official document for time complexity for OrderedDict. :)

Please feel free to correct me if I mis-read anything.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked the [Implementation of python Orderedlist object from Python mercurial repository](https://hg.python.org/releases/2.7.11/file/tip/Objects/odictobject.c). In the comments of odictobject.c file they stated:`One invariant of Python's OrderedDict is that it preserves time complexity of dict's methods, particularly the O(1) operations.`

Comment: Thanks Kun, vote up for your reply. I read the code repo for logics of their implementation and confused a bit for their logics of `popitem` implementation. I am wondering how it is implemented using `O(1)`? Normally there should be a heap or other similar data structure to maintain insert order, so that the pop from last or from first, they can always find the right item?

Comment: (cont'd) From the code implementation, I do not see they are using heap or other data structure, so I think you are correct they are using `O(1)` implementation, and if you could clarify a bit more how they achieve the performance using `O(1)`, it will be great. :)

Comment: Hi Kun, if you could advise on my above question, it will be great. Thanks.

Comment: That code you linked is beautiful

Comment: The implementation uses a doubly-linked list.  So removes at either end of the list is O(1).